# Attempting to calculate billing from time

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

[image]

I'm using a time tracking software that outputs to a csv. I know I can't just multiply my rate by the time value (see image, where I'm just translating the value to a cell formatted as "General"). What calculation can I put into D15 to make this work?

Comment: You will need to parse your "Time on Task" to hours and minutes, then perform the calculation, based on the number of hours and fractions of hours you spent on the task.  I suggest you make it easy on yourself, when you input the time, round up or down to the near quarter hour. This way you multiple a value by 1.5 hours (1 hours 30 minutes) or (1 hour) in the examples you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you see is because Excel has supported two different calenders, one with epoch coinciding with 31.12.1899 and the other with 1.1.1904. The difference in days (including one leap day) is 1462, which is also the value that creates your problem.

You can read more about the differences between 1900 and 1904 date systems [in this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel)

If your time records in the csv file denote pure time intervals (number of hours and minutes) and never include any date part, then you can simply subtract the integer part of the value and base your calculations on the desimal part only, f.ex.:

```
=(D15-INT(D15))*24*HourlyRate
```